# Empirically measuring time complexity of QuickSelect

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I know that the time complexity should be `O(N)`. However, when I'm testing it empirically, I get weird results. Can somebody please explain what's going on?

```
def insertPivot(array, start, end):
    pivot = end
    i = start
    j = end - 1

    while i < j:
        while array[i] < array[pivot] and i < j:
            i += 1
        while array[j] > array[pivot] and j > i:
            j -= 1
        array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
    
    if array[i] > array[pivot]:
        array[i], array[pivot] = array[pivot], array[i]
        pivot = i
    
    return pivot
    
def quickselect(array, k):
    start = 0
    end = len(array) - 1
    pivot = insertPivot(array, start, end)
    while pivot != k - 1:
        if pivot < k - 1:
            start, end = pivot, end
        else:
            start, end = start, pivot - 1
        pivot = insertPivot(array, start, end)
    return array[k - 1]
```

And here's how I'm getting my measurements

```
import random
import timeit
import numpy as np

av_times = dict()
for n in [10, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000]:
    times = list()
    array = list(range(n))
    for _ in range(10):
        random.shuffle(array)
        k = random.randint(0, n)
        times.append(
            timeit.timeit(lambda: quickselect(array, k), number=10)
        )
    av_times[n] = sum(times) / len(times)

xx, yy = zip(*av_times.items())
xx, yy = np.log(xx), np.log(yy)
m, b = np.polyfit(xx, yy, 1)
```

The slope coefficient `m` is `1.5`, which suggests that the time complexity is `O(N*sqrt(N))`

Answer (score 0):

`insertPivot` is of **O(N)** complexity indeed, since you increase `i` and decrease `j` until `j` is no longer greater than `i`. However, `insertPivot` is embedded into a while cycle inside `quickselect`. So, whatever the complexity of `quickselect`, that multiplies the complexity of `insertPivot`, since an algorithm of **O(n)** complexity is executed on each step of your loop. If `pivot < k - 1`, then you increase the left boundary of your interval. Otherwise you decrease to `pivot - 1`. So, in the loop you decrease the interval's size on each step by the difference between its left of right edge and pivot. Depending on what function you can use to approximate the number of steps you can determine what to multiply your N in the linear complexity with, resulting in the actual complexity.

Comment: "Otherwise you decrease end by 1" - no, you misread the code. It's setting `end` to `pivot - 1`, not `end - 1`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks for pointing that out! You are completely right. My lack of experience in Python made the code difficult to read to me, which caused this oversight :)